# PHP Converting an Image to add Multipart Form Data

Tags: php, image, forms, api, multipart

I am having some difficulty with an API. It has requested that I create a Multipart Form Data image

```
POST https://api.working.com/v1/detail/detail.example.id1/27f145d2-5713-4a8d-af64-b269f95ade3b/images/thumbnail/normal

------------------------------330184f75e21
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="icon.png"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

.PNG
imagedata
Response
```

I am trying to find some example PHP script that will convert an image into this format

The image file must have the name image in the multipart form data

I am racking my brain and combing the internet to find something that works for me.

Does anyone have a snippet they can share please to help?

Thanks

Rob

Comment: You can use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) to create a multipart request like that to upload an image to a server.

Comment: @drew010 Thats what I have been looking to do. Could you be more specific please? I clicked the link you provided, but it only goes to a list of differnt Curl types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a basic curl example showing how to do it:

```
$url = 'https://api.working.com/v1/detail/detail.example.id1/27f145d2-5713-4a8d-af64-b269f95ade3b/images/thumbnail/normal';

$data = array(
    'image' => new CURLFile(
        '/path/to/icon.png', 
        'application/octet-string',
        'icon.png'
     ),
    'some_other_field' => 'abc',
);

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

// do something with response

// to debug, try var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); and var_dump(curl_error($ch));

$ch = curl_init($url);
```

Check out the [CURLFile](http://php.net/curlfile) class for more info on file uploads, and [`curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) for more request options.